# Can this decimate scatter effect be done with nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I'd like to make a node group that with a "scatter" slider would make the texture scatter to bits as shown below. Can this be done with nodes?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the following effect with only a few nodes.

[image]

It is essentially just dividing the coordinate space up and walking it over.  What I can't do is track each individual pixel and make sure it's represented in the final scatter.  However, since you're dividing the UV space and not the image's pixels you effectively have infinite resolution choices.

[image]

Here's the final node tree, hope you can tell what's going on with my uncooked pasta.

[image]

Essentially we're using a *MixRGB* node where we give you the *Fac* handle as the Scatter input.  In the *MixRGB* node we're mixing between unmodified UV Coordinates and a set of UV coordinates with our modifications.

At the bottom here, there are lots of ways to generate this random output but I thought *White Noise* was pretty tailor-made for the job.

[image]

We generate a grid with a *Voronoi Texture* with *Randomness* set to 0.  I gave the *Scale* as another user input.  Throw the *Position* into the *White Noise Texture* and you've generated a map of values between 0 and 1.  We can then "normalize" the values for our purposes to a range between -0.5 and 0.5 and *Math* -> *Add* the result to (in this case) the X coordinate.

[image]

With enough divisions you lose track of the fact that things are sliding around.